# How to mentions workplaces in CV when they have been merged

Tags: resume

I have been working at place A for 2 years, after that the company A was merged with another company and formed a new company named B. How should I mention them in my CV so that recruiters does not mistake that for a job/workplace change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the accepted method of indicating a company being acquired on a resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/what-is-the-accepted-method-of-indicating-a-company-being-acquired-on-a-resume)

Comment: Why don't you just say that the companies merged?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Software Engineer for 4 years at B (known as A before merge in 2018)

Comment: or "at A (now [known as] B)"

Comment: @Kevin I don't like your way, because if people google old company names, they end up at dead websites. So I would put the current name first

Comment: I would probably lean towards what it was the majority of time you worked there.  If the merger happened six months into your five year stay there, I would definitely do it your way, or even just leave off the old name.

Comment: Considering a CV is an advertisement, I don't know how many people care if Your previous employer was merged, but I certainly wouldn't. I don't think it adds much. In my case the company's name has changed twice in my three years of employment, so I just use the latest one, without stating the change. Being in the UK, Company's house would show the name changes, if they cared that much.

Comment: I agree @Monstar. I would default to using just the current name, unless the previous firm which was absorbed in the merger had a better reputation than the merged whole, or was better known locally than the new name, or unless there is some other good reason. But merely being a stickler for the branding history of a firm is not a good reason. If there are multiple job titles to account for which traverse a company merger, it would be best to create a block for e.g. "Firm X (known as Firm Y before 2015)", and then put individual periods and job titles within that block.

Comment: @Steve, I agree. Write whatever would put you in the best light, without lying. (Though it would be nice to have opinions of hiring managers)

Comment: @Monstar, it would be nice to have some input from hiring managers, but even then one often gets a picture of incompatible superstitions and prejudices.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of putting things on one line is that it will speed comprehension.  Assuming that the first human read will be a fast skim, two/three lines will confuse things.  Also, the overall visual layout will lead the reader to assume that the person worked in more places, unless and until they read carefully.

Comment: Not the exact answer to the question but a useful tip

Answer (score 0):

To present the things as close to the reality, I would use the following:

> - from (date1) to (date2) : company A
> - from (date2) to (date3) : company B (as a result of company A being bought by / merged to company B)